# How to make width of body element stretch to the width of html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[**JSFiddle of SSCCE here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/wcvu68nc/6/)

I have a fullscreen `background-image` on `html`, like

```
html {
    background: url(flowers.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And I have a `background-color` applied to `body`, and its value has some transparency, like this:

```
body {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```

This way, as an overall look of the page, there is an image in the background peeping through a translucent (semi-transparent) overlay (body's background-color).

Then the body contains a table which has a number of columns, due to which horizontal scrolling is enabled.

The problem is that when the user scrolls horizontally, we see that the overlay which is `body`'s `background-color` ends with the viewport, after which there is naked `html`'s `background-image` with table-content floating over it.

The question is that how do I make the `body` stretch to the width of the `html`?

I tried giving `width:100%` to body and different positions to html and body, but that didn't help.

Comment: Add `width=100%`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wcvu68nc/14/  : also have a look at the `table` , the `html` had a problem, you close the `table` tag to early, i amended it.

Answer (score 1):

Use below css:

```
body {background:none}
body:before {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate solution you could use `linear-gradient` as part of the `background` declaration on the `html` element:

```
html {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0.75), rgba(255,255,255,0.75)),
                url(flowers.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

You may wish to check [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient) before implementing.

Answer (score 0):

give `background-color` from body and add that property in `table` like

```
.mdl-data-table {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
or in this css
.panel-h
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
{
```

Answer (score 0):

@Shivas solution is good but you would just have to add the `z-index: -1` on `body:before`.

On the other hand, why make page horizontaly scrolable when you can just make an element scrollable. Just the table.

Something like this:

https://codepen.io/ivandoric/pen/PRLKXJ

That way whole page doesn't have to scroll, because that could caouse a problem if you have some content above or below the table. It would just dissapear to the left. Which would look ugly.

My suggestion would be to do it like shown in the codepen.